# Custom Font Characters Separated?

Tags: android, eclipse, fonts, arabic

i  am creating an application and using a custom Arabic font.
When i launch my emulator the Arabic Letter/Characters are separated so its just like the Alphabet?
Is there a Fix for This?

Answer (score 0):

try this

http://mdictionary.wordpress.com/2011/02/10/connected-arabic-characters-for-android-apps/